# tkinter: global name is not defined

Tags: tkinter

I am always getting an error message when I try to run this code.
I have the Tkinter documentation and have read it. I am trying to put text into a field that will disappear once a person starts typing. Here is the code.

```
class MyGrid(Frame):
    def __init__(self, win=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, win)
        self.grid()
        self.mkWidgets()

    def mkWidgets(self):
        self.mytext = StringVar()
        self.mytext.set("Enter text here")
        self.e = Entry(bg='orange', textvariable=mytext, relief=SUNKEN, width=45)          
        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0)

app = MyGrid()

app.mainloop()
```

I always get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'mytext' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first rule of debugging: assume the error is telling the literal truth. In this case it is saying `mytext` is undefined. When I look at your code I have to agree: nowhere do you define a global variable named `mytext`.

You *do*, however, define something named `self.mytext`. You should use that in the following line of code:

```
self.e = Entry(bg='orange', textvariable=self.mytext, relief=SUNKEN, width=45)
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter. Tk()
```